# Node-RED ARM32 module in Azure Edge running on Raspberry Pi 4 prompting "EACCES: permission denied"

Tags: docker, node-red, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I am trying to run a Node-RED module [noderededgemodule](https://github.com/iotblackbelt/noderededgemodule) in Azure Edge running on Raspberry Pi 4.

I'm using the ARM32 container, but get the following error:

```css
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ iotedge logs nodered
fs.js:114
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, copyfile '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/settings.js' -> '/node-red/settings.js'
    at Object.copyFileSync (fs.js:1728:3)
    at copyFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:68:8)
    at onFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:53:25)
    at getStats (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:48:44)
    at startCopy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:38:10)
    at handleFilterAndCopy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:33:10)
    at Object.copySync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:26:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/red.js:108:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
fs.js:114
    throw err;
    ^
```

Comment: That error message is pretty clear, should give you a good start on where to look...

Comment: I understand that the module is trying to copy a file from that file location and that the permission is denied. The file location doesn't appear to exist however, so I'm not sure what my next steps should be.

Comment: Remember that the file locations are inside the Docker container...

Comment: I am afraid I didn't know that. Is there something wrong with the container then?

Comment: Do I need to change some permissions inside the container?

Comment: No, more likely the permissions on some mounted volume. I suggest you raise an issue against the project so the author can help you as this is very likely to be Azure Edge specific config.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: The question has been moved to [github](https://github.com/iotblackbelt/noderededgemodule/issues/6)